# Merge two tables and assign 1/0 in columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tools` (
  `pk_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk_id`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `features` (
  `pk_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `feature` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES tools(id));
```

Each tool may have multiple features. Also each feature may belong to different tools. In this case Many-to-Many relationship is done without the 3rd table. Feature is just repeated with a different primary key.

Now I want to write a SELECT statement to see all corresponding features for each tool as follows:

```
Tools  Feature1 Feature2 Feature3 Feature4
=========================================
ToolA  1        0        0        1
ToolB  0        0        1        0
```

How can I do this?

At the moment I wrote this statement but it does not assign 1 or 0, depending on the features of particular tool.

```
SELECT tools.title, features.feature
FROM tools
INNER JOIN features
ON tools.id=features.id;
```

UPDATE:

Following the comment of @sagi, I checked the following [link](http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-table-with-dynamic-columns/) and tried to adapt the code to my needs:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(pa.feature = ''',
      feature ,
      ''', pa.feature , NULL)) AS ',
      feature 
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM features;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT p.id
                    , p.title
                    , ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM tools p
                   LEFT JOIN features AS pa 
                    ON p.id = pa.id
                   GROUP BY p.id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

However I got an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '8,MAX(IF(pa.feature = 'feature 2', pa.feature, NULL)) AS ' at line 3
```

Comment: Do you know how many features there can be? If so you can use CASE on your select and them sum them, if not, you should use PIVOT

Comment: @sagi: No, the number of features is unknown to me. This is the case. Otherwise I would be able to find solution myself. I'm searching for some automatic way to do this.

Comment: @sagi: Could you give an example of using PIVOT?

Comment: Try this link: http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-table-with-dynamic-columns/

Comment: @sagi: I checked your solution. Please see my update. I cannot make this code working.

Comment: @sagi: The error was due to a blank space in column names. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tools.title,
       MAX(case when features.feature = 'Feature1' then 1 else 0 end) as Feature1,
       MAX(case when features.feature = 'Feature2' then 1 else 0 end) as Feature2,
       MAX(case when features.feature = 'Feature3' then 1 else 0 end) as Feature3
FROM tools
INNER JOIN features
ON tools.id = features.id
group by tools.title
```

Comment: In MySQL, you can simplify the aggregations to `MAX(features.feature = 'Feature1')`.

Comment: What if the number of features is large and I cannot apriori know all of them? It means I cannot manually do (case when features.feature = 'Feature1'..).

Comment: That would be a bit tricky. Perhaps sagi's `PIVOT` tip is the answer?

Comment: than you should use PIVOT